# multilevel java packages

Tags: java, package

how do i define multilevel packages in java

```
package foo;
```

one level package

```
package foo[.1oo[.2oo]];
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Where have you heard of "multilevel packages"? These don't exist. A package is just a namespace for classes, to avoid naming conflicts across the thousands of classes existing. You should explain us what you want to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't work because package names must start with a letter. This works:

```
package foo.bar.baz;
```

**N.B.** package names aren't hierarchical or nested in the way that they might look. A package name is simply an identifier for a namespace. That means that `package foo.bar.baz` **is not** truly a subpackage of `package foo.bar`.

See also:

- [The Java Tutorial: What is a package?](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html)
- [The Java Tutorial: Creating and Using Packages](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package

Comment: "package names aren't hierarchical or nested in the way that they might look. […] `package foo.bar.baz` is not truly a subpackage of `package foo.bar`".  Not true; subpackages are defined in the JLS as a hierarchical naming structure.  Though the only thing the language does with subpackages is prevent them from having the same name as a top-level type in that package (e.g. package `com.example.A` and class `com.example.A` cannot both exist).  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64018076/1108305